# Rotate SVG group indefinitely 360 degrees without CSS or Java

Tags: svg, svg-animate

This is my first time diving into SVG. Is it possible to rotate this group 360 indefinitely without css or javascript/jquery? So far I have it rotating in the top left corner but I cannot seem to figure out how to center it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd"> 
<svg width="576" height="576" viewBox="0 0 288 288" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
<g id="seed" transform="translate(144,144)" stroke-width="2" stroke="black" fill="none" >
<circle cx="0" r="64" />
<circle cx="64" r="64" />
<circle cx="64" r="64" transform="rotate(60)" />
<circle cx="64" r="64" transform="rotate(120)" />
<circle cx="64" r="64" transform="rotate(180)" />
<circle cx="64" r="64" transform="rotate(240)" />
<circle cx="64" r="64" transform="rotate(300)" />
<circle cx="0" r="128" />
<animateTransform attributeType="xml" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" values="0 0 0; 360 0 0" dur="5s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
</g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your animateTransform overwrites the transform on the `<g>` element. Looks like you want to provide an additional transform which you would with the attribute `additive="sum"`

```
<svg width="576" height="576" viewBox="0 0 288 288" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
<g id="seed" transform="translate(144,144)" stroke-width="2" stroke="black" fill="none" >
<circle cx="0" r="64" />
<circle cx="64" r="64" />
<circle cx="64" r="64" transform="rotate(60)" />
<circle cx="64" r="64" transform="rotate(120)" />
<circle cx="64" r="64" transform="rotate(180)" />
<circle cx="64" r="64" transform="rotate(240)" />
<circle cx="64" r="64" transform="rotate(300)" />
<circle cx="0" r="128" />
<animateTransform attributeType="xml" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" values="0 0 0; 360 0 0" dur="5s" additive="sum" repeatCount="indefinite" />
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Wow, nailed it! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

PaEDIT: My bad you probally mean JavaScript.

Okay you can calculate the center with JavaScript and a nice SVG-method called getBBox();

A method to return center of SVG-elements so your  should also be possible. Okay piece of code

```
 var svg = {    
 getCenterPosition:  function(elem) {

        // use the native SVG interface to get it's boundingBox
        var bbox                = elem.getBBox();
        // return the center of the bounding box
        return {
            px: (bbox.x + bbox.width / 2).toFixed(2),
            py: (bbox.y + bbox.height / 2).toFixed(2)
        };
    }
}
```

svg.getCenterPosition(yourGElementAsParameter); will return the center-coordinates. (web developer console or Firebug or something) Then you can set these coordinates in your attributes but don't alter the viewbox or anything it will now rotate around it's center.